# how to use subselect annotation to define view entity class

Tags: hibernate

I want to define a readonly view entity class. Thats why I have written like following class. But according to jars which are used for the project does not contain Subselect and Synchronize annotation class. In order to achieve this issue i tried to change some jars with old ones. But occured another incompatible exceptions. I'd learn strongly if which compatible jar list includes org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect.class

Developed in ADF platform and Weblogic 10.3
Using these hibernate releases:

```
hibernate3.jar
hibernate-annotations-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-3.3.0.ga.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-3.4.0.GA.jar
hibernate-validator-4.1.0.Final.jar
```

This composition was enough and useful for me until required of using Subselect annotation class

Plz help me 
Thanks in advance
Brgds

```
import com.arsivist.structure.BaseEntityView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Immutable;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Subselect;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Synchronize;


@Entity(name = "IntegrationDepartment")
@Immutable
@Subselect("SELECT * FROM DEPARTMENTVIEW")
@Synchronize("DEPARTMENTVIEW")
public class IntegrationDepartment extends BaseEntityView
{
private IntegrationDepartment dependentDepartment;
private String code;
private String name;
private int departmentLevel;
private boolean excludeDistribution;

private Collection<IntegrationDepartment> departmentList;

public IntegrationDepartment()
{
entityName = "IntegrationDepartment";
departmentList = new ArrayList<IntegrationDepartment>();
}

public IntegrationDepartment(int id, String code)
{
entityName = "IntegrationDepartment";
departmentList = new ArrayList<IntegrationDepartment>();

this.id = id;
this.code = code;
}

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
public int getId()
{
return id;
}

public void setId(int id)
{
this.id = id;
}

public void setDependentDepartment(IntegrationDepartment dependentDepartment)
{
this.dependentDepartment = dependentDepartment;
}

@ManyToOne(targetEntity = com.roketsan.integrationmodel.entity.IntegrationDepartment.class)
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPENDENTDEPARTMENTID")
public IntegrationDepartment getDependentDepartment()
{
return dependentDepartment;
}

public void setCode(String code)
{
this.code = code;
}

@Column(name = "CODE")
public String getCode()
{
return code;
}

public void setName(String name)
{
this.name = name;
}

@Column(name = "NAME")
public String getName()
{
return name;
}

public void setDepartmentLevel(int departmentLevel)
{
this.departmentLevel = departmentLevel;
}

@Column(name = "DEPARTMENTLEVEL")
public int getDepartmentLevel()
{
return departmentLevel;
}

public void setDepartmentList(Collection<IntegrationDepartment> departmentList)
{
this.departmentList = departmentList;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "dependentDepartment")
@JoinColumn(name = "DEPENDENTDEPARTMENTID")
public Collection<IntegrationDepartment> getDepartmentList()
{
return departmentList;
}

public void setExcludeDistribution(boolean excludeDistribution)
{
this.excludeDistribution = excludeDistribution;
}

@Column(name = "EXCLUDEDISTRIBUTION")
public boolean isExcludeDistribution()
{
return excludeDistribution;
}

@Override
@Transient
public int compareTo(Object object)
{
if (!(object instanceof BaseEntityView))
throw new ClassCastException();

IntegrationDepartment baseEntity = (IntegrationDepartment)object;
Integer comparableElementA = getDepartmentLevel();
Integer comparableElementB = baseEntity.getDepartmentLevel();

return comparableElementA.compareTo(comparableElementB);
}

public String toString()
{
return "" + getCode();
}
}
```

Comment: Have you found a solution so far? TIA!

Comment: Actually there is no difference with a view or table for hibernate i noticed. So it depends to your db grantes abit. I gave up SubSelect annotation because i do not need to use besides the views which i wanted to use belongs to another datasource(P.U) I coded view entities like as normal table and i just used them for querying in dao classes