# Hibernate annotation equivalent of <set><subselect>

Tags: java, hibernate

We're trying to migrate to Hibernate annotations from .hbm.xml files.

I'm searching for the annotation equivalent of the following XML:

```
<set name="someSet">
    <subselect>
        <![CDATA[some long SQL query]]>
    </subselect>
    <key column="fk" />
    <element type="MyUserType" column="value" />
</set>
```

I know there is `@Subselect`, but I'm not sure how to use it for my problem.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14584890/how-to-use-subselect-annotation-to-define-view-entity-class), but as far as I understand it, I don't want to define a View for the entire entity, but just for that one field.

Declaring it on `MyUserType` doesn't achieve my goal, as it would apply to everywhere `MyUserType` is used. Do I need to subclass `MyUserType`, or is there a better way?

Comment: why not google it then?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I added some more info to my question. I've been searching for some time to no avail.

Comment: you can't add `@Subselect` to a specific field. It is used for the whole entity. the best thing you can do if you really need the subselect for that field, is to create a `View` and then map that field to the view with `@ElementCollection` and `@CollectionTable`

Comment: What does this have to do with JPA? since you explicitly want a "Hibernate annotation" and only quote Hibernate HBM XML

Comment: @DN1 The thought was that there might be a JPA-spec only solution, but I've removed the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up going with database views to solve this problem.

Unfortunately it separates the query from the code, but this is the method with the least chance of breaking something accidentally.

As far as I can tell, there is no direct `@Subselect`-annotation to replace that hbm construct.

Answer (score 0):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Fetch(FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-fetchmode-subselect

Comment: This is not what the question is asking.